# Define a function with specific permutation properties

Tags: functions, function-construction, programming

I want to define a function `evaluate[f_[x__]]` which acts on an arbitrary function `f[a,b,c,d]`. The function `f` takes any kind of argument and the function `evaluate[f_[x__]]` has to deal with the following properties

- The function `f` is defined for specific values for `a,b,c,d`, which may be numbers, list, functions etc.. For example,consider the definitions `f[1,2,3,4]=1` and `f[1,2,p[3],p[4]]=2` where `p[a_]` are undefined functions/tensors. Notice the order matters.

I want the function `evaluate` returning the function `f` evaluated on the specific permutation for which I have given a definition of `f` itself. For example,

- `evaluate[f[3,4,1,2]]` must return `f[1,2,3,4]=1` since among the permutations of `{3,4,1,2}`, `f` is only defined on `{1,2,3,4}`.
- `evaluate[f[p[3],p[4],1,2]]` must return `f[1,2,p[3],p[4]]=2` since among the permutations of `{p[3],p[4],1,2}`, `f` is only defined on `{1,2,p[3],p[4]}`.
- `evaluate[f[x__]]` must return `False` is multiple permutations are defined and if no permutations are matched.

Is there any intelligent and clever way to write a function with these properties?

Comment: Please clarify: do you want `evaluate` to permute arguments of `f`(or any function?) to a form for which term rewriting finds a rule for arguments of `f`? What if there are multiple permutations which are permissible?

Comment: @kirma I didn't understand your first question. I want `evaluate` to permute arguments of only the function `f`. It is supposed there are no multiple permutations which are permissible. I can add the requirement that if multiple permutations are permissible, return `False`.

Comment: OK. What if no permutation matches?

Comment: @kirma It may return `False`. Let me edit the question

Comment: In addition to my accepted answer, I would suggest taking a look at `Orderless`, that is `SetAttribute[f, Orderless]` for `f`. This doesn't handle no-matches or multiple-matches cases, but can auto-permute arguments when evaluating the function.

Comment: Can I use `SetAttribute[f, Orderless]` for only the first two arguments and the last two arguments separately?

Comment: I think you can accomplish this by using `OrderlessPatternSequence` in the function definitions (instead of all-encompassing attribute), but this can become a bit awkward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
ClearAll@evaluate;
evaluate[f_[args___]] := 
  With[{perms = 
     Select[Unevaluated@*f @@@ Permutations[{args}], ValueQ]}, 
   If[Length@perms == 1, perms[[1, 1]], False]];
```

(`args` are evaluated normally when `evaluate` is called.)

Now, let's define a function:

```
ClearAll@f;
f[2, 4, 3, 1] = 3;
f[a, b, c, d] = 1;
f[b, c, d, a] = 1;
f[5, x_?Positive] := x + 10;
```

This results:

```
evaluate[f[1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

> 3

```
evaluate[f[b, a, c, d]]
```

> False

```
evaluate[f[foo, bar]]
```

> False

```
evaluate[f[-1, 5]]
```

> False

```
evaluate[f[1, 5]]
```

> 11